# In Google Sheets, link to column by name rather than column number

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, index-match

```
=index(nfl_an_raw!$1:$808, match(J8, nfl_an_raw!$AH:$AH, 0), H$4)
```

Here is an index-match we are doing in Google Sheets. Our main problem with this is `nfl_an_raw!$AH:$AH`. The column ordering in `nfl_an_raw` are subject to change, and we would much rather be explicitly grabbing this column by its column name `game_key`, rather than by its column index `$AH:$AH`.

Is this possible in Google Sheets? Seems like it would be straightforward but I haven't found a solution yet.

**Edit:** the `name` of the column is `game_key` because the cell AH1 is `game_key`.

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GVEFVNEs78bhL61WbDXT0o_8Z7ToQaxpTU1woEAB-sY/edit?usp=sharing` - see cell B3

Comment: I will share a dummy spreadsheet for this, one moment

Comment: spreadsheet has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(nfl_an_raw!$1:$808, MATCH(B1, INDIRECT("nfl_an_raw!"&
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH("game_key", nfl_an_raw!$1:$1, 0), 4)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH("game_key", nfl_an_raw!$1:$1, 0), 4), 1, )), 0), B2)
```

Comment: yep makes sense, I will probably tweak to remove both `1`s rather than just the latter 1, but this definitely works